# CSS/HTML - How can I write superscript in a <input type="button"/>?

Tags: html, css, superscript

Let's say I have something like this:

```
    <input type="button" value="2(8)">
```

I want to have the "(8)" as a superscript how?

Note: I know that you can do it with:

```
     <button>2<sup>8</sup></button>
```

But I want to do it without that...

Comment: You can't write 2⁸ in an input button, it simply can't be done :-p

Comment: You can't, as you can't have HTML content in attributes such as `alt` on images, `title` on links, etc It must be plain text. Or you could use UTF-8 symbols but I wouldn't recomment that for compatibility purposes (do the font have the relevant character?) and accessibility (how many scren readers and other ATs won't read those UTF-8 characters?)

Comment: When you say you want "to do without that", you should explain why, so we know what are the acceptable solutions.

Comment: The one's that fits in with the question...

Comment: Yeah I actually tried with ascii and it worked, but some browsers doesn't suppor the ascii symbols :(

Comment: Well, there's [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/uEgFQ/) if you don't want the button element. Be sure to add the relevant header telling the browser the charset is UTF-8.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use the [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) ?

Comment: the line height fails :(

Comment: You need to override a bunch of weird things on `button`, see: http://fvsch.com/code/button-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject a seperate style with the `::after` pseudo class.

**CSS**

```
button::after {
    content: attr(data-superscript);
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button data-superscript="8">2</button>
```

Using the `attr()` property, you can dynamically change the superscript value based on the `data-superscript` attribute.

Note that this is CSS3, and it's *not* compatible with all browsers.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc6Rx)**

Comment: before `2`? make `button::after` -> `button::before`.

Comment: It's not compatible with most screen readers either (only VoiceOver I think). They'll only read "2" and lose important information conveyed via CSS and the pseudo.

Comment: I noted that from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Use the unicode superscript 8 character, and make sure you're document is valid as UTF-8:

```
<input type="button" value="2⁸" />
```

Comment: Yeah but if I want to have a superscript "x" after the 2 how?

Comment: @Mich', if you can't find the character in unicode, use a `<button>` element, or an image.